# How do I execute a parted command with a C function?

Tags: linux, partition, c

I would like to execute the Linux command "parted" through a C language function?

I am using Linux Ubuntu , eclipse.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, in your C program, you should add a line like this:

```
int res = system("/bin/parted <options>");
```

The C program must be executed with root privileges (or run through `sudo`). The `res` variable contains the result of the command (see `man system` for details).

As an alternative, use a command of the exec family (see `man exec` for details).

For instance, this should read the partition table for the `/dev/sdb` disk.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     int res = 0;
     res = system("/bin/parted -s /dev/sdb print > /var/log/mypartedlist.txt");
     if (res == -1) /* command not executed  */
        exit(1);
     else /* command ok */
     {
          if (WIFEXITED(res))
          {
              if (WEXITSTATUS(res) == 0)
                  printf("Command executed ok\n");
              else
                  printf("Command had a trouble\n");
          }
          else
          {
              printf("Problems running system\n");
              exit(2);
          }
     }   
}
```

Comment: I don't need special includes?

Comment: For `system`: `#include <stdlib.h>`.  For `exec`:`#include <unistd.h>`.

Comment: Sorry I'm new with that , what you mean "options"

Comment: You mean "int res = system("/bin/parted /media/sf_ImageFileNexus/Nexus6.img ");"

Comment: options as the path ?

Comment: finally want i need is the partition table of the device so i want to create an output file with that data, how can i do that in minimum effort?  thanks in advance !!

Comment: I don't have parted on my system, but with `<options>` are meant the options you must give to `parted` to perform your task.   If you want, for example, run a `ls -l`, the `<options>` are "`-l`".

Comment: aaaaaa ok !!!!!

Comment: From the official documentation: "When invoked from the command line, Parted supports the following syntax:  

`# parted [option] device [command [argument]]`".  To read the partition for, i.e., `/dev/sdb`, the command is `/bin/parted /dev/sdb print`.   To obtain a file with the partition data, try to redirect the output to a file (something like `/bin/parted /dev/sdb print > /a/place/to/write/a/file/partiton.txt`). Try from command line, first.

Comment: Addendum: the full command is (I think!):  `/bin/parted -s /dev/sdb print`.  Try it on the command line.

Comment: It does work in the terminal !!!!  Excuse me for taking your time but i still don't understand how to do it in a c program.

Comment: I've added some code to my answer.

Comment: I did some change and it works !!!

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     int res = 0;
     res = system("parted -s  /media/sf_ImageFileNexus/Nexus6.img  > PTablelist.txt print");
     if (res == -1) /* command not executed  */
    exit(1);
     else /* command ok */
     {
          if (WIFEXITED(res))
          {
              if (WEXITSTATUS(res) == 0)
                  printf("Command executed ok\n");
              else
                  printf("Command had a trouble\n");
          }
          else
          {
              printf("Problems running system\n");
              exit(2);
          }
     }
}